# Assetic doesn't update styles without cache:clear

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I have an app.less that imports everything (less) else if I comment a line in app.less app styles doesn't render the commented part, but if I change something in that imported less file, anything changes, I have to do `cache:clear` and to clear the browser cache to see the new style loaded...

Answer (score 2):

Assets that are imported from another stylesheet (less, sass, whatever) will not be recompiled when they change, even if you use `php app/console assets:dump --watch`. See [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075812/how-can-i-force-assetic-to-render-assets-each-time-the-page-is-reloaded) and [this issue in the `AsseticBundle` issue queue](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/39).

Answer (score -2):

I came upon the same problem. This is caused because LESS is using your `window.localstorage` to save the rendered css file. For testing you could put in javascript

```
<script> /* Provisory for dev environment: */ window.localStorage.clear(); </script>
```

however this causes your page to load really slow. i have not found another options for this just yet.