# LessCSS Assetic @import cache disabling

Tags: php, css, symfony, less, assetic

I have a "small" problem that is stealing insane amounts of time from me.

I use **assetic** with **lesscss** filter in **symfony2.1** . The problem is, Assetic(?) doesn't notice file changes in imported files using `@import`. For example:

global.less:

```
@import "colors";

body {
    background: @backgroundColor;
}
```

colors.less:

```
@backgroundColor: #333;
```

Now, if I change my `@backgroundColor` in *colors.less*, nothing happens. I have to add whitespace in my *global.less* file, and only then it recompiles my CSS.

At first, I checked if it was APC accelerator problem maybe so I disabled it but it wasn't. Then I checked assetic github and found this: [Issue #79](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/79#issuecomment-9810791)

I tried it but story is still the same, as if I haven't done anything. Then I checked if my **Assetic** version has this feature at all since I found out that "ArrayCache" class was merged 2 months ago, so I've set my *composer.json* to require "dev-master" Assetic Bundle (which was updated mid-december, so it has new Assetic version merged into it). Still no success.

I'm out of ideas now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, Assetic can't find changes into imported less document.

To fix that I use [LessElephantBundle](http://knpbundles.com/matteosister/LessElephantBundle) wich work only on develop environment. It will scan less files for changes, and, if that fail you can use a force_compile var.

On assetic:dump --env=prod, you don't need it, assetic will regenerate all your css without cache.

Comment: In case anyone wants more background info, the bug this post mentions is [here](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/79).  There's also [another related answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351809/328817) if anyone wants to explore further.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still happens for me 2 years later.  The way I fixed it was by setting up a File Watcher in PHPStorm, which runs the `touch` command on the main LESS file each time one of the LESS files referenced by @imports are modified.  This busts the cache, and recompiles the CSS files.